# Feeding all files matching a pattern into stdin of a script

Tags: bash

I have a folder with 10000 txt files, and a shell script that, if used on a single file, works in the following way:

```
cat some_file.txt | ./myscript.sh
```

However, I am trying to create a loop that passes the script to every file in that folder. Here is what I've tried this far--and dosent work:

```
for f in /Users/me/desktop/folder*.txt; do ./myscript.sh “$f”; done
```

Any ideas how to add the "cat" command in my script?

Comment: Your quotes are Microsoft SmartQuotes, not real quotes. Any chance your code was copied-and-pasted from a Word document or an Outlook email or such?

Comment: That is to say, `“$f”` is a completely different thing from `"$f"`.

Comment: (As another aside, using a `.sh` extension -- particularly for a bash script, which is *not* a POSIX sh script -- is less than ideal form: It falsely implies that your script can be run with `sh yourscript.sh`, and moreover means that if you rewrote it in an entirely different language you'd either need to keep a misleading extension or modify all callers to use the new name).

Comment: How can you tell the difference between OSX's on-by-default smart quotes and Microsoft SmartQuotes?

Comment: @thatotherguy, ...OSX does something that asinine? I had no idea. *sigh*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one instance of `myscript.sh` will suffice for the content of all the files:

```
find /Users/me/desktop/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'folder*.txt' \
  -exec cat {} + | ./myscript.sh
```

...this will have `find` invoke a single `cat` instance for each batch of files up to the operating system's limit on command-line length, and have the results of all of those `cat` instances fed in a single stream into one instance of `myscript.sh`.

---

Alternately, if you want a different instance of your script for each file:

```
for f in /Users/me/desktop/folder*.txt; do ./myscript.sh <"$f"; done
```

Comment: your find would need to have depth = 1 or it could find files in the subdirs, which wouldn't be equivalent.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, yes, I had an edit adding `-maxdepth 1` already underway.

Comment: just to be pedantic :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, ...something about pots and kettles comes to mind, were I to object. :)

Comment: That's why I allowed myself to comment on that. I knew you wouldn't mind.

Comment: I am getting file or dirrectory not found errors. 
 ( -bash: ./myscript.sh: No such file or directory)  (-bash: /Users/me/desktop/folder*.txt: No such file or directory)

Comment: @Panoid, well, *do* those files exist? Obviously, you need to use names that are appropriate for your system, your current working directory, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes the files exist

Comment: Obviously not, insofar as the script is concerned. Maybe it's `cd`ing somewhere where they don't exist; maybe the file has CRLFs and the CRs are being interpreted as part of the names... playing guessing games is worthless. Generate an actual reproducer someone else can run to see the same bug.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, your second code works. Indeed, it was cd ing to another location. So I moved the script  and the txt files in the same folder and then used the following: for f in *.txt; do ./myscript.sh <"$f"; done